# Type trait to determine a data member's access specifier from a pointer-to-member to that member

Tags: c++, reflection, template-meta-programming

I'm looking for a type trait that will allow me to find out if a pointer-to-member points to a `public` data member or not.

Example :

```
template<auto ptr>
struct is_public_member_ptr 
{
    // Possible?
};

class foo 
{
public:
    int i;
private:
    int j;

    static_assert(is_public_member_ptr<&foo::i>::value == true);
    static_assert(is_public_member_ptr<&foo::j>::value == false);
};
```

At first I considered using SFINAE to try and dereference the pointer-to-member and see if it worked, expecting substitution to fail for pointers to private members. Obviously that didn't work, you could only check if you are able to get the pointer-to-member in the first place. Once you have it, dereferencing will always succeed, even for `private` members.

This leads me to believe that there is no way to check the access specifier strictly from a pointer-to-member. That information isn't encoded into the pointer-to-member. But, it is possible to recover the original class to which the pointed member is a member of. So maybe there is some trick I missed.

Is this type trait achievable?

An ideal solution would be compatible with C++14, but solutions for any C++ version are fine too.

Comment: AFAIK, access control is not a part of the type system, so I don't think there is a check you can use for that.

Comment: Also, because some template trickery can actually *bypass* access control and gain access to `private` members (see [this](http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html) and [this](http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2011/12/access-to-private-members-safer.html))

Comment: Perhaps you can write a check that deals with member name instead of the pointer.

Comment: @user7860670 Thanks for your suggestion. The context is as part of a type reflection system, it deals with a `constexpr` array of pointers-to-members. So using identifiers is not possible. Perhaps the whole thing could be rewritten to use identifiers, but then it would need to rely heavily on macros, which I don't think is worth it.

Comment: What a coincidence! I've worked on some sort of reflection system recently too. It was supposed to be a sort of robust (and macro-free) alternative for boost.hana with some twists. tl;dr; at the end i've turned it other way around: alternative object system for c++ where all the reflection-related stuff and those twists come directly from declarations. In your case it would be something like declaring a tuple of member traits such as `member<access::_private, int>` instead of normal C++ `class` with fields.